# wp_enqueue_script creates Fatal Error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The following is what I have in my code for a custom theme. However I'm having issues with attaching my custom_script to the footer.

```
09    <?php    
10    function my_scripts_method() {
11        wp_enqueue_script(
12            'custom-script',
13            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
14            array('jquery')
15        );
16    }
17    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
18    ?>
```

yields the following error for me.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare my_scripts_method() (previously declared in ***filename_removed***.php:12) in ***filename_removed***.php on line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you already have a function called `my_scripts_method`.  Just change the name of the function:

```
function my2_scripts_method() {
    // blaa blaa blaa
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my2_scripts_method');
```